# Appending arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, append

I have three arrays which represent category IDs in Wordpress, all with the format `$base_cat_id['term_id']`. What I want to do is assign a post to three of these categories using the following function:

```
wp_set_post_categories($entry['post_id'], $base_cat_id + $generic_n_cat_id + $specific_n_cat_id);
```

However, when I do this the post is only assigned to the first two categories. Am I using the right method to add these arrays together?

Edit:

I got this to work by doing the following:

```
$cat_ids = array($base_cat_id['term_id'], $generic_a_cat_id['term_id'], $specific_a_cat_id['term_id']);
wp_set_post_categories($entry['post_id'], $cat_ids);
```

It's not pretty. But I found that using array_merge with the same string ID does not work, as it overwrites the values. Union does not work either as I can only use a union for two arrays. Please let me know if there is a better way!

Comment: Note that the `+` array operator does [perform a union](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php). Therefore, I believe your problem lies in the array format.

Answer (score 4):

Use the function array_merge(). Its arguments are as many arrays as you are merging and it returns those arrays merged in one array, so it returns an array.

like this:

```
wp_set_post_categories($entry['post_id'], array_merge($base_cat_id, $generic_n_cat_id, $specific_n_cat_id));
```

Caveat: your if your arrays are multilevel, then you might get weird results. For more info check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: +1 for beating me to the same answer. I also added a link to the docs.

Comment: I just tried this and the post was only assigned to the last category. It seems like array_merge is not keeping all three categories together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what's in your array other that 'term_id', but try using this:

```
wp_set_post_categories($entry['post_id'], array_merge($base_cat_id, $generic_n_cat_id, $specific_n_cat_id));
```

Comment: All of the variables have "term_id".